# What is the easiest and fastest way to spawn ghasts on the Nether roof?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Basically, I have the following set up in the nether roof. (Version: 1.19)

[image: screenshot of setup]

I made an 8x8 nether rack platform, and it goes up by about 100 blocks. The biome is the Nether wastes. Will this eventually spawn a ghast? (I've been struggling to get ghast tears because they keep falling in the lava ocean, so I want to spawn one in the Nether roof to easily get ghast tears.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the wiki, you would need to be in Nether Waste, basalt deltas, and soul sand valley biome. You are in Nether Wastes, so that's fine.
You have a 8x8 platform, they require a 5x5 or more.
Ghasts require 4 blocks of free space above the platform.

Is there a nether fortress below?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will work eventually, however due to the heightmap of mob spawning - where mobs spawn less frequently at higher Y values, you aren't leaving many spawn spaces available.

You can restrict the spawning to just ghasts by including a light source as ghasts spawn at any light level but zombified piglins need 11 or lower - and this should net you more ghast spawns